# Datagridview checkboxcolumn state to check based on another datagridview textboxcolumn value

Tags: vb.net

I got this code where if textboxcolumn value in a datagridview is equal to 1 datagridview checkboxcolumn state is checked. But sad to note that its not working.

below is the code;

```
 Private Sub LoadTUITIONFees()
    sqlCon.Open()
    CMD = sqlCon.CreateCommand
    CMD.CommandText = ("SELECT TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee Code], TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.Specification, TESTFeeSETUP.[Amount/Cost], FEESList.[Type of Fee], TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee Status], TESTFeeSETUP.Date " &
                        "FROM TESTFeeSETUP INNER JOIN FEESList ON TESTFeeSETUP.FeeID = FEESList.FeeID INNER JOIN TESTFeeSETUPSubTable ON TESTFeeSETUP.[Fee Specification] = TESTFeeSETUPSubTable.[Specification ID] " &
                        "WHERE (FEESList.[Type of Fee] = 1)")
    Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader()
    If Reader.HasRows Then
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        DT.Load(Reader)
        dgvTuitionFees.DataSource = DT
        dgvTuitionFees.Columns(2).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        dgvTuitionFees.Columns(0).DisplayIndex = 6

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvTuitionFees.Rows
            If row.Cells(5).Value = 1 Then
                Dim cell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = row.Cells(0)
                cell.Value = cell.TrueValue
            Else
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Reader.Close()
    sqlCon.Close()
End Sub
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code. according to some, it works with them but mine does not.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Rather than looping thru control rows (many which may not even be showing!), you should respond in an event - either CellFormatting or RowPrepaint (very hard to tell what you are doing).  You could force FeeStatus (???) to a bool so a checkbox is automatically used by using an alias in the SQL.  Your code is also leaking and ought not be reusing connections.

Comment: So how will i do it? i would welcome for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CellFormating event on the DataGridView and use something like this:

```
Private Sub dgvTuitionFees_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvTuitionFees.CellFormatting

    Select Case e.ColumnIndex
        Case 5
            If (e.Value = 1) Then
                dgvTuitionFees.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = True
            Else
                dgvTuitionFees.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = False
            End If

        Case Else

    End Select
End Sub
```

In this case if value in column 5 (`Case 5`) is equal to 1 (`e.Value = 1`),
CheckBox in column 1 (`Cells(1).Value`) will be set to `True`
Bare in mind that column 5 must be visible on the form to be able to capture `e.ColumnIndex = 5`